# SQL an ID in one group and an id from another

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have a request where I need a count where a participant completed an activity under one id (the gateway to completing other things) and then an id in a list of other ids. Right now, this code is only coming back with the the a count of the one id but not saying that one id complete + the other ids.

```
select
    plan,
    count(*)
from
    table
where
    id = 1234
    and
    id in (1354, 5842, 8565)
group by
    plan
```

How can I get this where it gives me the count of data from id 1234 plus ids in (1354, 5842, 8565), rather than just a count of data from the id 1234

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: You **do** know how the `AND` operator works, right? Your `WHERE` predicate will only match rows where `Id = 1234`, so checking for `5842` and `8565` is moot because those **aren't** `1234`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It seems you've fallen for the "SQL looks like a *natural* English-language query" trap.

  - Fun fact: **it isn't**.
  - You may have heard of COBOL: the business-rules programming language that resembles English-language, but COBOL actually has rigid, inflexible grammatical and semantic rules that betray the friendly-looking syntax.
  - SQL is very much the same: it's a very, very thin veneer of approachability over a very hostile and academic branch of mathematics called [Relational Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_calculus).
  - I curse the SQL language high-priests every time I have to type-out their *decreed* unnecessarily verbose and logically inconsistent `SELECT e FROM a WHERE b GROUP BY c HAVING d ORDER BY f` statements.

**ANYWAY!...**

Change your query to remove the `id = 1234` so it uses only the `id IN ( ... )` clause:

```
select
    plan,
    count(*)
from
    table
where
    id in (1354, 5842, 8565)
group by
    plan
```

If you want a query that better follows your described mental-model, then use a `UNION [ALL]`  query:

```
SELECT
    plan,
    COUNT(*) AS "count"
FROM
    table
WHERE
    Id = 1354
GROUP BY
    plan

UNION

SELECT
    plan,
     COUNT(*) AS "count"
FROM
    table
WHERE
    Id in ( 5842, 8565 )
GROUP BY
    plan
```

---

Explanation:

- The `AND` operator in SQL represents a [Logical Conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction): *that is* the left-hand-side and right-hand-side of the `AND` operator must be `true`.

  - Given that `Id` is your primary-key (at least, I hope it is!) it is impossible for any single row in `table` to have an `Id` value which is *simultaneously* equal to `1234` and `5842`. That's why your query is only matching 1 row in total.

    - Also, surprisingly, SQL engines **do not warn you** that a predicate is logically impossible or otherwise has redundant sub-expressions.

      - My personal opinion is that if a computer language *allows* for loose syntax it should yield warnings whenever *something ain't right* is observed. This is another reason why I dislike SQL.
- `x IN ( a, b, c )` is semantically *identical* to `( x = a OR x = b OR x = c )`.

  - The `OR` is a Logical Disjunction, and **not** an English-language "or": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction

    - This is another *gotcha* in the fallacy of SQL's "natural" English-language *veneer*.
- I assume you thought the `Id = 1234 AND Id IN ( a, b, c )` used "and" as a Logical Disjunction, not a Logical Injunction. Hence the fix is to replace the `AND` with an `OR`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  plan,
  count(*)
FROM
  table
WHERE
  id in (1234, 1354, 5842, 8565)
GROUP BY
  plan
```

This gives you the count of data from id 1234 plus ids in (1354, 5842, 8565).
As other user mentioned, providing more information would help receive a better answer. Like what's the current output and what's the desired.
Also, not necessary if simple, but having the table description wouldn't hurt (output of `DESCRIBE table;`)

Thanks